# Updating useState returning empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a simple component which is supposed to return all messages in database.

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const _ = require('lodash');

const ChatList = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [err, setErr] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMessages = async () => {
      const allMessages = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/chat');
      const messagesMapped = Object.keys(allMessages.data)
        .map((id) => allMessages.data[id])
        .map((message) => _.omit(message, '_id'))
        .map((message) => ({
          ...message,
          delete: (
            <Button
              label="Delete"
              className="p-button-outlined p-button-danger"
              onClick={() => handleDelete(message.id)}
            />
          ),
        }));
      setMessages(messagesMapped);
    };
    fetchMessages();
  }, []);

  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    axios
      .delete(`http://localhost:5000/chat/${id}`)
      .then((res) => alert(res.data[0]))
      .then(() =>
        setMessages((messages) =>
          messages.filter((message) => message.id !== id)
        )
      )
      .catch((err) => setErr(err.response.data));
  };
  console.log(messages);
  return (
    <div>
      <Menu />
      <div className="chat-list-div">
        {err && <h1>{err}</h1>}
        <DataTable value={messages} responsiveLayout="scroll">
          <Column field="id" header="Id of message" />
          <Column field="user" header="User" />
          <Column field="message" header="Message" />
          <Column field="delete" header="Operations" />
        </DataTable>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChatList;
```

I'm a bit confused, because if I write inside `handleDelete` in axios:

```
setMessages(messages.filter(message => message.id !== id)))
```

it seems to return empty array so my `DataTable` becomes empty.

It works fine if I write it like this:

```
setMessages(messages => messages.filter(message => message.id !== id)))
```

The problem is that I don't understand why it works with the 2nd option and does not with the 1st one. I've been using React for half a year and have always written the 1st option and it always WORKED.
For example, I have another component which returns games, and the same logic works fine.

```
const [games,setGames] = useState('')
const handleDelete = (id) => {
        axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/games/${id}`)
            .then((res) => alert(res.data[0]))
            .then(() => setGames(games.filter(game => game.id !== id)))
            .catch(err => setErr(err.response.data))
    }
...

{games && games.map(game => (
                    <p>{game.id}</p>
))}
```

Is someone able to make me understand why in 2nd component it (making only `setState(prevState.filter)`, not `setState(prevState => prevState.filter)` works and in 1st it doesn't?

//edit

Another component (`GamesList`):

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Menu from '../main/Menu';
import { Card } from 'primereact/card';
import { Button } from 'primereact/button';
const axios = require('axios');
const _ = require('lodash');

const GamesList = () => {
  const [games, setGames] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchGames = async () => {
      const allGames = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/games');
      const gamesMapped = Object.keys(allGames.data)
        .map((id) => allGames.data[id])
        .map((game) => _.omit(game, '_id'));
      setGames(gamesMapped);
    };
    fetchGames();
  }, []);
  console.log(games);
  const [err, setErr] = useState('');
  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    console.log(games);
    axios
      .delete(`http://localhost:5000/games/${id}`)
      .then((res) => alert(res.data[0]))
      .then(() => setGames(games.filter((game) => game.id !== id)))
      .catch((err) => setErr(err.response.data));
  };

  const header = (
    <img
      alt="Card"
      src="images/usercard.png"
      onError={(e) =>
        (e.target.src =
          'https://www.primefaces.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/placeholder.png')
      }
    />
  );
  const footer = (gameId) => (
    <span>
      <Button
        label="Delete"
        icon="pi pi-times"
        className="p-button-outlined p-button-danger"
        onClick={() => handleDelete(gameId)}
      />
    </span>
  );

  return (
    <div className="gameslist-main">
      <Menu />
      <div className="gameslist-cards">
        {games &&
          games.map((game) => (
            <Card
              title={game.id}
              key={game.id}
              subTitle="Game"
              style={{ width: '25em' }}
              footer={footer(game.id)}
              header={header}
            >
              <h3>Winning numbers: {game.winningNumbers.toString()}</h3>
              <p>
                Players:{' '}
                {game.players.toString().length === 0 ? (
                  <span>NONE</span>
                ) : (
                  <ul>
                    {game.players.map((player) => (
                      <li key={player.login} className="gameslist-card-player">
                        <span className="gameslist-card-player-span">
                          {player.login}
                        </span>
                        <span className="gameslist-card-player-span">
                          ({player.numbers.toString()})
                        </span>
                        <span className="gameslist-card-player-span">
                          <span className="guessed-numbers">
                            {
                              game.winningNumbers
                                .toString()
                                .split(',')
                                .filter((num) =>
                                  player.numbers
                                    .toString()
                                    .split(',')
                                    .includes(num)
                                ).length
                            }
                          </span>
                        </span>
                        <span className="gameslist-card-player-span">
                          <span className="separator">/</span>
                        </span>
                        <span className="gameslist-card-player-span">
                          <span className="no-guessed-numbers">5</span>
                        </span>
                      </li>
                    ))}
                  </ul>
                )}
              </p>
              {err && <p>err</p>}
            </Card>
          ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default GamesList;
```

Comment: You can refer to the useState section of this official doc https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html which explains it

Comment: I found out that in Games component (in the end of my post) if I console.log(games) inside handleDelete, it is visible, but when I console.log(messages) inside handleDelete in my ChatList component, it's empty array, why is that if they are almost the same files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) that your `useEffect` creates when it passes for the first time.

The second solution that you use, where you send a callback, uses current array value and filters that at the moment of usage.

```js
setMessages(messages => messages.filter(message => message.id !== id))
```

At the moment of the execution of that callback, `messages` has the current value set by the result of that `axios.get` method in initial `useEffect`

To reduce your confusion i changed `messages`, which is the name of your state, to `currentMessages`:

```js
setMessages((currentMessages) =>
  currentMessages.filter((message) => message.id !== id)
);
```

**In your first solution**:

```js
setMessages(messages.filter(message => message.id !== id)))
```

`messages` is an empty array since `useEffect` triggers only once, and at that moment `messages` is "closed" and is an empty array since initial value is set like that:

```js
const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
```

This behavior has to do with functional closure, mentioned at the beginning, at it is "fixed" in react by using that callback in `setMessages` method.

In your other component `GamesList` where you don't need to use set state method with callback, you have `footer` method that renders part where you assign `handleDelete` to be called gets `games`'s state new data every time `games` gets set. Because setting state re-renders your component, that part gets generated again and `handleDelete`, when called, will have new `games` value.

Comment: Thank you for that. I know that useEffect triggers only once, but it sets propely the messages, so it is not empty array, that's why I'm confused when going into handleDelete, why when I console.log(messages) inside handleDelete, it console.logs empty array? I can't understand why in my component games, it works well (it sees the games inside handleDelete) and it doesn't work inside messages...

Comment: Would it mean that the first solution „remembers” the messages from the initial state and doesn’t see that the useEffect updates it even though I use the function handleDelete after updating the state? 
I get your point, the only thing I don’t understand is that in another component it works fine and seems the games as updated state. 
It also turned out that if I make at the end of file a simple button which goes into handleDelete onClick, it also sees the messages updated. Might setting the button inside object be the problem there?

Comment: The problem is closure that remembers `messages` to be empty array. That `useEffect` locks everything as it is at the beginning. This means all callbacks that will be called later on such as `handleDelete` will use old `messages`. That is the nature of closure in JS functional part, not sure if that has to do with other functional languages.
As for the other component, i cannot see where you use `handleDelete`. Can you fill in the rest of the code, and i will modify my answer to include that part too?

Comment: I've just edited my post :)

Comment: Great. I will add more explanation for that part. As i thought, the other component gives `handleDelete` new data on every render. So it will have new state every time it gets used.